# Pymongo insert_many BulkWriteError

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert the following list of dictionaries named `posts` to mongo, and got a `BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred` error which I don't know how to fix.

`posts:`

```
[{'#AUTHID': 'fffafe151f07a30a0ede2038a897b680',
  'Records': [
   {'DATE': '07/22/09 05:54 PM',
    'STATUS': 'Is flying back friday night in time to move the rest of his stuff then go to work the next morning... great.'},
    ......

   {'DATE': '07/19/09 04:39 PM', 'STATUS': 'is stealing his net by the lake'}]},

 {'#AUTHID': 'fffafe151f07a30a0ede2038a897b680',
  'Records': [
   {'DATE': '07/22/09 05:54 PM',
    'STATUS': 'Is flying back friday night in time to move the rest of his stuff then go to work the next morning... great.'},
   {'DATE': '07/19/09 04:39 PM', 'STATUS': 'is stealing his net by the lake'},
  ....
```

The code I used:

```
collection = db.posts
collection.insert_many(p for p in posts )
```

But then I got an error that says `BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred`  and only managed to import the first dictionary (corresponding to the first `#AUTHID`)

I found a link that describes similar situation but it doesn't explain much about why this happens or how to solve this issue. It's under the **_Why does PyMongo add an *id field to all of my documents?*** in the following link:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/doc/faq.rst#id25

Comment: Based on your sample `posts` above, it seems like the document is duplicated because the content is the same. Please note that the FAQ says about inserting **single document** as multiple. I suspect your `dict(s)` is the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Not to late to answer here, you almost there. I am not sure if the [FAQ](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) updated but please read it properly:

> when calling `insert_many()` with a list of references to a **single** document raises BulkWriteError

Note that it says **single** or in other word, **same instance**. The example in the FAQ shows how to produce the error with the same instance. You can check if it is the same by using `id()` to display the memory address. In fact, I can see the content of your documents is the same. Most probably (but not necessarily) it is the same instance.

```
print id(posts[0])
print id(posts[1])
```

If any of the dict having the same instance, then something wrong during preparing the `posts` variable. Just make sure all list items should have different instance because you are inserting (many) different documents!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIZQQ.png)
in this output records are store which are in list.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient 
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['post']
posts = [{'#AUTHID': 'fffafe151f07a30a0ede2038a897b680',
    'Records': [
        {'DATE': '07/22/09 05:54 PM',
            'STATUS': 'Is flying back friday night in time to move the rest of his stuff then go to work the next morning... great.'},


        {'DATE': '07/19/09 04:39 PM', 'STATUS': 'is stealing his net by the lake'}]},

    {'#AUTHID': 'fffafe151f07a30a0ede2038a897b680',
        'Records': [
        {'DATE': '07/22/09 05:54 PM',
        'STATUS': 'Is flying back friday night in time to move the rest of his stuff then go to work the next morning... great.'},
        {'DATE': '07/19/09 04:39 PM', 'STATUS': 'is stealing his net by the lake'}]}]
collection = db.posti.insert_many(p for p in posts )
```