# BulkWriteError on insert_many when ordered=False

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have some records and am trying to `insert_many` using the following with pymongo:

```
db.collection.insert_many(records, ordered=False)
```

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838280/how-to-ignore-duplicate-key-errors-safely-using-insert-many) that setting `ordered=False` should allow me to skip duplicates, and I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42389548/7542939) that if there are duplicates within the list itself that it will throw the error. But there are no duplicates within the list being bulk written, and I'm still getting `E11000 duplicate key error collection.` Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Are you using pymongo? What version? When you say that you are "getting" that message, what do you mean? What's the full response from the database for the operation?

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76395778/mongodb-insertmany-skip-the-same-id-field-to-avoid-code-11000/76396057#76396057 with example how it works (the behavior will be the same for all drivers and in the shell). `But there are no duplicates within the list being bulk written` - the duplicated key should be mentioned in the error message

Answer (score 2):

You will get a `E11000` duplicate key error if either:

- A record you are trying to add has the same `_id` field as an existing record in the database; or
- You have added a unique index and a record you are trying to add has matching unique index fields with an existing record

Even if your `records` are themselves all different, you may still get this error if there are exiting records in the database.

When pymongo throws the error, you will get some additional details. If you can add the full stack trace to your question then we might be able to help more.

Comment: It's because there are records with the same `_id` field. But I thought `ordered=False` was supposed to deal with this?

Comment: Not quite, `ordered=False` means that MongoDB will attempt to load the remaining records rather than just stop on the first error. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#behaviors